# How do i connect to Amazon EC2 Server with PHP and SSH

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm unable to connect to Amazon EC2 with a pem file using PHP

```
$pemFile = file_get_contents($this->_pemFileLocation);

$out = "";
$key_private = openssl_pkey_export($pemFile, $out);
```

I need to connect and get a connection object returned from `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()`, so i can run terminal commands, on an Amazon EC2 instance or any other server using a pem file.

Comment: I have given up on such tasks before and ended up using exec(`ssh -t`) instead. While it is definitely not the solution that you are expecting, it can be used as a temporary workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, using phpseclib http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

```
$key = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();

$key->loadKey(file_get_contents("key.pem"));

$ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2("18.191.164.167");

/* ubuntu is the username used by amazon ec2 */
if (!$ssh->login("ubuntu", $key)) {
   throw new \Exception('Login Failed', E_WARNING);
}else{
    /* run a command and get the results as a string */
    var_dump($ssh->exec("ping davidclews.com"));
}
```